# How long before the series start does Caprica make first contact with the other human colonies?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, tv, caprica

I've just recently started watching "*Caprica*" (a canceled "*Battlestar Galactica*" spin-off), and I was wondering at what point in the chronology of the series do the various human colonies make first contact with one another?

Have the different human colonies always had contact with one another?

Was there a particular time when the colonies met each other?

When does this all occur in relation to the series?

Comment: I"m so disappointed by the cancellation of Caprica. The series starts off very slowly with a rather unclear direction and then in the last few episodes it completely blows your socks off. It's just not fair. :(

Comment: @Nathan Taylor - Though I agree, I removed the F-bomb from your statement.  FYI, I love to swear personally, but I think it's against policy of the Stack Exchange Network and the community doesn't take to kindly to it.

Comment: That's understandable. It's a rather sour subject for me, if you couldn't tell.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As I understand, the twelve planets of Twelve Colonies are in the same star system (4 stars near each other), so they probably were in some contact with each other from the start of the settlement of the planets. The civilization did not originate on the Twelve Colonies (one of which is Caprica), the people come from Kobol. There also was a thirteenth tribe of colonists, which was rumored to go to Earth and all contact with it was lost.
See [Battlestar Galactica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Colonies) on Wikipedia.

Comment: +1 The analogy here would be us sending colonies to the rest of the solar system just before Earth blows up. We'd have "The Seven Colonies".

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the twelve colonies were all founded, at the same time, by refugees from Kobol, with the assistance of the Lords of Kobol. I never heard anything to suggest that they were ever out of contact with each other.

This is distinct from the Thirteenth colony, which went off in the other direction, and lost contact with the Twelve very early.